# Apache httpd setup and installation

Tags: apache, apr

I am trying to install Apache HTTP server locally in my box as a regular user (non-root).

I have downloaded Apache 2.4.1 version of Apache HTTP server [http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi]. However when I am trying to build and install locally in my box I am getting below error:

```
httpd/httpd-2.4.1 1059> ./configure
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library ...

checking for APR... no
configure: error: APR not found.  Please read the documentation.
```

I am not sure what dependency it is looking for - I mean the download package does not contains it? What I need to do to build / deploy Apache HTTP server?

Comment: @JimGarrison, Then why is it not closed / moved?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

When it tells you `Please read documentation` it means that you should go read Apache documentation ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html ) which tells you to

> download the latest versions of both APR and APR-Util from [Apache APR](http://apr.apache.org/),
>   unpack them into ./srclib/apr and ./srclib/apr-util (be sure the
>   domain names do not have version numbers; for example, the APR
>   distribution must be under ./srclib/apr/)

then do

```
./configure --with-included-apr
```

Comment: `
httpd/httpd-2.4.1 1062> ./configure --with-included-apr checking for chosen layout... Apache checking for working mkdir -p... yes checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep unknown-linux-gnu checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library ... configure: error: Bundled APR requested but not found at ./srclib/. Download and unpack the corresponding apr and apr-util packages to ./srclib/.
`
Which is the corret site to download and where should I install

Comment: I downloaded apr libs but now during configuring it says -

configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/

Trying dowloading and installling same

Comment: you should install pcre/libpcre package using your Linux distribution package manager

Comment: I installed libpcre in my local directory 'make install DESTDIR=..' but Apache make is not able to pick up from there- it is rather looking into /usr/local/lib (root owned) folder:
server/mpm/event/libevent.la os/unix/libos.la -L/usr/local/lib -lpcre  -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1

I tried Apache configre with --with-pcre-libs to local ones but it does not work. Note I cannot install libpcre.a in /usr/local/lib

Comment: Sweet success .. need to change lines in Makefile: #PROGRAM_LDADD = buildmark.o $(HTTPD_LDFLAGS) $(PROGRAM_DEPENDENCIES) $(PCRE_LIBS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(AP_LIBS) $(LIBS) ----> PROGRAM_LDADD = buildmark.o $(HTTPD_LDFLAGS) $(PROGRAM_DEPENDENCIES) $HOME/lib/usr/local/lib/libpcre.a $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(AP_LIBS) $(LIBS)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link - I successfully installed Apache 2.4.1 in my local directory under my home directory

Comment: Note the `./srclib` means the `srclib` directory inside your `httpd-xxx` directory

Comment: Why dont they just include that for you?  This seems like a waste of time

Comment: as u have mentioned --with-included-apr can u please give me the link where i could find these included flags

Comment: @user2383973 try `./configure --help`

Comment: can u tell me what i am doing wrong in APR installation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260365/apache-apr-and-apr-util-installlation

Comment: Is there any benefit of installing apr and apr-util separately as independent packages beforehand instead of just including their source in apache?

Comment: @DavidWilliams, The more time wasted, the more money sysadmins earn. If everything's perfect and "just works" perfectly all of the time, how else do you think sysadmins make money?

Comment: Sure this is old but according to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/configure.html#installationdirectories: The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) is part of the httpd source distribution and will automatically be build together with the HTTP server. If you want to use an already installed APR instead you have to tell configure the path to the apr-config script. You may set the absolute path and name or the directory to the installed APR. apr-config must exist within this directory or the subdirectory bin.

Answer (score 40):

For Ubuntu 11.10 this option seems to be working well:

```
 # APR

wget http://mirrors.axint.net/apache//apr/apr-1.4.6.tar.gz

tar -xvzf apr-1.4.6.tar.gz

cd apr-1.4.6/

./configure

make

make install

cd ..

# APR Utils

wget http://mirrors.axint.net/apache//apr/apr-util-1.4.1.tar.gz

tar -xvzf apr-util-1.4.1.tar.gz

cd apr-util-1.4.1

./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr

make

make install

cd ..

# Apache

wget http://apache.petsads.us//httpd/httpd-2.4.1.tar.gz

tar -xvzf httpd-2.4.1.tar.gz

cd httpd-2.4.1

./configure --enable-file-cache --enable-cache --enable-disk-cache --enable-mem-cache --enable-deflate --enable-expires --enable-headers --enable-usertrack --enable-ssl --enable-cgi --enable-vhost-alias --enable-rewrite --enable-so --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/

make

make install

cd ..
```

You can find more about it below

Source: [VaporCreations.com](http://vaporcreations.com/article/compile-install-configure-php-v540rc1-atop-apache2-v240-under-ubuntu-110-oneiric-ocelot#)

Comment: unless your the root user, you'll need to prefix "sudo" on the "make install" calls

Comment: Thanks. I was missing a few parameters to ./configure

Comment: After `make install` how to start httpd service on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo) ?

Answer (score 28):

If you have Debian/Ubuntu you can just:

```
apt-get install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
```

Then `./configure`

Done

Comment: this help me for ubuntu users

Answer (score 21):

Here are the steps of how I installed apache-httpd on a non-root users:

1. Download and extract apache-httpd-2.4.2 (but before ./configuring,
   making and installing it, follow the steps below:)
2. Download and extract APR & APR-UTIL into "./srclib/apr" &
   "./srclib/apr-util" folders. This requires ./configure
   --with-apr=./apache/httpd-2.4.2/srclib/apr  (and) --with-included-apr (options).
3. Download, extract, ./configure (with) --prefix=localURL, make and
   make install PCRE into "./pcre" folder. This requires ./configure
   --with-pcre=/home/username/apache/pcre (option).
4. Configure apache-httpd by entring following command (I like to
   enable certain options as written in the command below):
       ./configure --enable-file-cache --enable-cache --enable-disk-cache
   --enable-mem-cache --enable-deflate --enable-expires --enable-headers --enable-usertrack --enable-cgi --enable-vhost-alias --enable-rewrite --enable-so --with-apr=/home/username/apache/httpd-2.4.2/srclib/apr --prefix=/home/username/apache/httpd-2.4.2/ --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/home/username/apache/pcre
   Note: When configuring apache-httpd, use option "--enable-ssl" ONLY if OpenSSL is installed otherwise DON'T enable it.
5. Now on the command-line, enter 'make' and 'make install' command.
6. Open and configure the 'httpd.conf' file e.g.:
   "vi /home/eddie_kumar/apache/httpd-2.4.2/conf/httpd.conf"

> **IMPORTANT**: don't forget to change the default port from 80 to something else e.g. 8080, this is especially important for non-root
>   user. (How to? open httpd.conf  ->  search "Listen 80"  -> change it
>   to "Listen 8080".

And that's it, now open your browser enter "localhost:**8080**", it should display "It works!".

Comment: If you're a debian user just do "apt-get install libpcre3-dev"

Comment: After `make install` how to start httpd service on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo) ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using fedora, you can use **yum** to install **APR, APR-Util and PCRE**. You'll also need to download apr-devel, apr-util-devel and pcre-devel.

That being said, you can just run the following command on your terminal and no more "*configure: error: APR not found.. ..APR-Util and PCRE*" errors.

```
yum -y install arp apr-devel apr-util apr-util-devel pcre pcre-devel
```

I'm using fedora 17 and planning on using a shell script to setup apache 2.4.3. So **yum** works pretty slick instead of manually downloading apr, apr-util, and pcre.

Comment: Fantastic! Its unclear you need the -devel versions. This is the best answer if you are fedora or redhat, or an amazon ec2 AWS instance which is redhat.

Answer (score 1):

1, You need APR (apache portable runtime), which is core component of apache web server

2, If you wnat to do make install, you may need root account

3, Even if not, apache can not start to listen on unprivileged port (lower then 1024) without root account

4, gain root or ask someone with root to install apache from official repo(I don;t know which distro you run) like using yum, apt-get, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Apr or pcre related errors require the source to be downloaded and Apache HTTPD "configure" process needs to be made aware of these source locations on your file system. For instance: if you downloaded the source for APR at ./srclib (relative to apache httpd) then you would use
--with-included-apr
as the configure option.

On the other hand if you want to not build but install APR / APR-UTIL, then you need the following on CentOS / RedHat:
 yum install apr-util-devel apr-devel
However it might so happen that the APR version provided by yum does not match what is expected by this version of Apache httpd. In that case you could download APR and APR-UTIL and use the --with-included-apr option.

You could also build PCRE utilizing the same "configure, make, make install" process and then continue where you left off building Apache httpd.
Or you could install pcre:
    yum install pcre-devel

If while building PCRE: you see "compile: unrecognized option" then perhaps you would need other dependencies as well: Please see the details at:
http://khanna111.com/wordPressBlog/2012/09/11/94087-2/
It also covers "mod_deflate" and "zlib" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps

```
tar -xvf httpd-2.4.1-customized.tar -C ../
#Balancer folder will be created
tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.1.tar.gz  -C /balancer/
cd ->/balancer/openssl-1.0.1
./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl/ shared zlib-dynamic enable-camellia
make depend
make
make install
tar -xvzf pcre-8.30.tar.gz -C ../balancer/

/balancer/pcre-8.30
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/pcre/
make
make install
```

remove pcre and openssl

Answer (score 0):

**Installing and compiling the Apache server on Ubuntu machine**

**step 1:Install the Java JDK**

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk

sudo gedit /etc/environment

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11"

source /etc/environment

echo $JAVA_HOME
```

verify the java version

```
javac --version
```

**** install Other required packages:**

```
  sudo apt-get install apache2-dev -y 

sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

**Step 2 :To Install Apache HTTP Server**

**#1 For ubuntu ,install development tools including the C compiler:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

**#2 Download  and  Extract the required files**

assuming that all the files have been downloaded into the  ~/Downloads directory

Download the Apache HTTP Server httpd-2.4.41.tar.gz from  Apache download page (https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)

and following required libraries for compiling the apache HTTP server:

- apr-1.7.0.tar.gz(http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi)
- apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz(http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi)
- pcre2-10.34.tar.gz (ftp://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/) http://pcre.org/

****Read Requirements Section(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html)***

**#3 Extract the tar files**

- tar  -xvf    httpd-2.4.41.tar.gz
- tar  -xvf   apr-1.7.0.tar.gz
- tar  -xvf   apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
- tar  -xvf   pcre2-10.34.tar.gz

after extraction you should see following list of directories in ~/Downloads

- httpd-2.4.41
- apr-1.7.0
- apr-util-1.6.1
- pcre2-10.34

**#4 Create a directory for the apache HTTP Server**

*make sure to give all rights to this directory  so that while compiling files can be read/written

```
 sudo mkdir /home{your username here}/apache
```

To give all permissions to a apache directory :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home{your username here}/apache
```

**#5 copy the arp and arp-util directory into the  ~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.41/srclib/**

```
cd ~/Downloads

mv  apr-util-1.6.1  ~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.41/srclib/apr-util

 mv  apr-1.7.0  ~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.41/srclib/apr
```

**#6 Configure the sources for compilation.**
The --prefix option can be used to install the Web server in a location where you can write files.

```
cd ~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.41/


./configure  --prefix=/home/{username here}/apache --with-pcre=~/Downloads/pcre2-10.34
```

***NOTE:***
If you have some problems while running above command,you can also try

insallting pcre in /usr/local/pcre, using

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre
make
sudo make install

commands and then by running folllowing commands:

```
   cd ~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.41/
```

./configure  --prefix=/home/{username here}/apache  --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre

make

```
  sudo make install
```

If you still face some problems ,make sure that ~/apache and its nested directory have read/write permissions. if not run   `**sudo chmod -R 777 /home{your username here}/apache**` command again.

**#7 Compile Apache HTTP Server.**

```
cd ~/Downloads/httpd-2.2.25

sudo make
```

**#8 Install Apache HTTP Server.**

```
cd ~/Downloads/httpd-2.2.25

sudo make install
```

**Optional**
**#9 To Prepare Your Hosts File**

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

27.0.0.1    localhost  www.example.com

```
sudo gedit /home/{your username here}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

and copy:

```
Listen 8000

ServerName www.example.com:8000
```

**#10 Test the installation to ensure Apache HTTP Server is working.**

```
/home/{your username here}//apache/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Comment: #./apachectl -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 66 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_file.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_authn_file.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory