# Apache installation; libpcre error

Tags: apache, pcre

When installing Apache on Ubuntu 11.10, I get the following error:

> configure: error: APR not found. Please read the documentation.

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436860/apache-httpd-setup-and-installation), then, I get the error below:

> configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

1. Download PCRE from [PCRE.org](http://pcre.org/)

2. Compile it with a prefix and install it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre
make
make install
```

3. Go back to where your Apache installation is and compile Apache with PCRE:

```
--with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
```

Comment: I had to designate the pcre config location explicitly like `./configure --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/pcre-config` in CentOS 6.3

Comment: Does the httpd make process statically link with PCRE? or do I need to include them with the compiled httpd stuff if I tar it and share it?

Comment: Same here, I needed to state the full path name of the file for RHEL 5: --with-pcre=/usr/local/bin/pcre-cofnig

Comment: Eric the spelling mistake for config in your comment wasted my two hours x( please edit

Comment: and finally after several hours my command ./configure --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre2-config is successful.. Never give up!!!!! :)

Comment: Works on Oracle Linux 6.10 with step three (3) as `--with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre2-config` instead of `--with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre`.

Comment: i had to give it the full path to the script `pcre2-config` too

Answer (score 19):

For me (Fedora Linux), it was enough to just install the pcre-devel: `yum install -y pcre-devel`. Didn't even have to use `--with-pcre` afterwards.

Comment: This was all I needed in Ubuntu as well. Do `sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev` (or, you know, whichever package/version is available in your time, Future Boy), then go back and try exactly the same options on `./configure` as got the error originally. Should work now.

Comment: Works fine for RedHat 6, too.

Answer (score 10):

### Debian

In a clean installation of Debian 9.5, during the installation of Apache it is necessary to have some packages and libraries to avoid errors. Next I show the type of error and its respective solution

> Configuration

- configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

  `$ sudo apt-get install build-essential`
- configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/

  `$ sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev`

Then I make the configuration indicating that it is installed in the path `/usr/local` and not in `/usr/local/apache2`, otherwise I will have library errors. The idea is that the libraries created for httpd end in `/usr/local/lib` so that the [dynamic linker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457917/301835) knows them.

```
$ configure --prefix /usr/local
```

---

> Compilation

And for the compilation the following the installation of some packages also would avoid us errors in a clean installation of Debian.

- xml/apr_xml.c:35:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory.

  `$ sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev`.

It is recommended to use the -j3 parameter to make the compilation faster. Although it could also be ignored.

```
$ make -j3
```

Answer (score 4):

I was other problem compiling apache2 in CentOS with pcre. I installed pcre in other location "/custom/location/pcre" and configure command throw the following error

```
configure: error: Did not find pcre-config script at "/custom/location/pcre"
```

to solve it changing the flag `--with-pcre=/custom/location/pcre` to `--with-pcre=/custom/location/pcre/bin/pcre2-config`

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and using  ./configure --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre2-config solved it for me - wonder why was this ever downvoted !!

Answer (score 2):

BTW, on CentOS 7.6 before building httpd, please install pcre-devel

```
`$ sudo yum install pcre-devel`
```

Comment: can you put some explanation here so it help to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

In **RHEL 3** is not necessary setting parameter `--with-pcre` pointing to pcre-config. Only need `pcre` path

My configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
```

Comment: Thanks, I just removed quotes (") in prefix param

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

./configure --prefix /u01/apache  --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre2-config

Comment: I also had to point to the config in the bin directly.  Possibly because I had installed pcre with a custom prefix?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
`sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev`

In ubuntu