# UNIX: ./configure is not generating Makefile

Tags: unix, makefile, installation

I'm trying to install the Apache web server from source code to a Fedora 14 VM. I've run ./configure multiple times already, and can see Makefile.in and .win but no 'Makefile'. When I run the 'make' command, I get the following error:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Can someone please tell me what's keeping it from generating a Makefile?

Comment: What output do you get from the `./configure` operation - specifically, are there any error messages, and does it say it is creating files?  Have you read the instructions on how to configure.  Where did you get the source code from (is it a tarball or did you get it direct from a source repository by cloning or whatever the correct operation name is)?

Comment: I get this error:

configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/

after which I followed:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663180/http-install-error-in-libpcre

but it still tells me that the 'pcre-config' is not found. I checked the directory and it contains 'pcre2-config', but the PCRE still doesn't configure properly.

Comment: OK; comments in the other question suggest `./configure --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/pcre-config`.  If you have `pcre2-config` instead of `pcre-config`, maybe you should specify the name to `pcre2-config` instead?  Or maybe there's a way to specify PCRE2 instead?  Or get the PCRE software (still available) and install that instead of (or as well as) PCRE2.

Comment: I did :/ went back to where my Apache installation is and used `./configure --with-pcre=usr/local/pcre/pcre2-config` but it keeps checking for pcre-config.

Comment: Then give it what it wants (the spoiled brat :D).  Go get PCRE 8.37 instead of PCRE2 10.10.  The download site is ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/.

Comment: Did you try extracting httpd a second time into a new directory?  I was able to build httpd 2.4.12 with apr 1.5.2 and apr-util 1.5.4 and PCRE 8.37.  I was able to use this configure command line: `./configure --prefix=$HOME/oss --with-apr=$HOME/oss/bin/apr-1-config --with-pcre=$HOME/oss --with-apr-util=$HOME/oss`, where I install most open source software under `$HOME/oss` (except Perl and GCC; they get installed in separate directory hierarchies of their own).