# How do I solve apache installation error, on Oracle Linux?

Tags: pcre, oraclelinux

I get the same error as in this question on a oracle linux 8.7. I have tried all the sugested solutions but i'm still getting the same error.

[Apache installation; libpcre error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663180/apache-installation-libpcre-error)

any idea what I can do?

1. Download PCRE from PCRE.org
2. Compile it with a prefix and install it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre
make
make install
```

3. Go back to where your Apache installation is and compile Apache with PCRE:

```
--with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
```

I tried this same error message. then I tried this:

```
sudo yum install pcre-devel
```

with the same result.