# configure: error: APR not found. Please read the documentation

Tags: apache, fedora, apr

I am trying to install apache in my linux machine. But when I tried `./configure --prefix = /usr/local/apache` it shows an error `configure: error: APR not found.  Please read the documentation`. I tried to install `apr` with `yum install apr apr-deve` and it says

`Package apr-1.4.6-1.fc15.x86_64 already installed and latest version`
`No package apr-deve available.`

`Nothing to do`
What should I do now? Please excuse I am a newbie to LINUX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436860/apache-httpd-setup-and-installation

Comment: Is `apr-deve` a typo?  If not, you meant `apr-devel`.

Answer (score 45):

Actualy I had to install aprutils also... So try using:

```
sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, but using centos 6.4.  I tried sudo yum install libapr1-dev, and likewise with libaprutil1-dev, both times yum said I already had it installed, but my problem is not fixed.

Comment: Hi, LeandroCR, Is there any way to install for Mac OS. I tried with brew install apr, but it is showing: Warning: apr-1.5.2_3 already installed, it's just not linked. 
But i am not able to find the apr folder location

Comment: Hi @AbijithMg have, have you tried to run a `brew doctor` or `brew link apr`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried brew link. Later it worked. Anyways thanks for the reply.!

Answer (score 36):

In the directory where you have installed the apache httpd distribution there is a directory that is called `/srclib`

You cd into that directory `cd /srclib`.
Make sure you are in that folder. Now open your browser and go to http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi
and download the apr-*.tar.gz files into this directory.

```
wget <link>
```

Unzip and extract them into srclib directory
after extracting make sure you rename the apr-* directories to just "apr" and "apr-util", respectively. For example:

```
mv apr-1.6.5 apr
mv apr-util-1.6.1 apr-util
```

Now, it should read the .apr files from that folder.
After that it will ask for `apr-util` too, make sure you follow the same procedure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked on my Mac!

Comment: Worked on CentOs 7

Comment: It gave me another error : `configure: error: pcre(2)-config for libpcre not found ` on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 9):

If your install on apache 2.2 or less than add flag
--with-included-apr

If you are using 2.4 than you can go to https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and download the latest apr and apr-util. Unpack them and move them into the apache source file into /srclib. Make sure they are named apr and apr-util not apr.x.x.x. Then you can use the --with-included-apr flag

Answer (score 3):

For my linux rig, I got past this by downloading the apr-dev package using the local package manager:

```
opkg install libapr-1-dev
```

That was on Angstrom linux, so your command version will likely be different, replacing opkg with apt-get or whatever your distro's package manager is.

Comment: I am having the same problem, this solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of doing this
download latest apr and apr-utils from https://apr.apache.org/

```
tar xzvf apr.XXX.tar.gz
tar xzvf apr-util,XXX.tar.gz
```

**Solution 1**
    mv apr.XXX httpd.XYZ/srclib/apr
    mv apr-util.XXX httpd.XYZ/srclib/apr-util

you should be able to see

```
ls httpd.XYZ/srclib/apr-util
apr apr-util
```

now cofigure apache via

```
./configure --with-included-apr --other-options-that-you-want
```

**Solution 2**

```
mv apr && ./configure && make && make install
mv apr-util && ./configure && make && make install
mv httpd.XYZ/
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr -other-options-that-you-want
```

NOTE : /usr/local/apr (CENTOS),your Distro might use different one

Answer (score 2):

For RHEL Linux, install the following packags:

```
yum install apr-devel apr-util-devel pcre-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download APR and APR-UTIL packages.
install the above downloaded packages from source  using below commands
./configure -prefix=
make 
make install

Then run your above mentioned command as below
./configure -prefix= -with-apr= -with-apr-util=

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev`  use this command in linux

Answer (score 0):

The following command works on my mac.

Prerequisites:

```
brew install apr
brew install pcre
```

In fact, the link is missing, so http can't be found

```
brew link apr
brew link pcre
```

Copy the prompt you see

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/apr/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/apr/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/apr/include"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/apr-util/bin:$PATH"
```

then, try again

```
source ~/.bash_profile
./configure
```