# Apache Apr and Apr-util installlation?

Tags: apache, apache2

I am installing Apache for first time in ubuntu 12.04 and i looked up in the link [Compiling and installing apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html)

It says we should have APR and APR-util first i follow the procedure and untar them into

`/usr/local/srclib/apr` and `/usr/local/srclib/apr-util` directory. 
Every where it is written

```
./configure's --with-included-apr
```

Now i just do `./configure` in `/usr/local/srclib/apr` after that i do `./configure` in `/usr/local/srclib/apr-util` then it throws me error `configure: error: APR could not be located. Please use the --with-apr option.`

then i add `/configure --with-apr` it throws an error

```
error: --with-apr requires a directory or file to be provided.
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: where did you unpack apache httpd sources?

Comment: i have done the installation

Answer (score 11):

Try running this:

`./configure --with-apr=<directory path where apr is installed>`

Eg: If your APR installation exists at `/usr/local/apr`(default installation location of APR), you should run:

`./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr`

Answer (score 1):

As you are running `./configure` in Apache source directory,  `./srclib` means srclib directory within Apache directory, not in /usr/local.
Suppose you place your Apache directory as /usr/local/httpd-2.x.x, then the path for apr and apr-util are as follows:

```
/usr/local/httpd-2.x.x/srclib/apr

/usr/local/httpd-2.x.x/srclib/apr-util
```

Now you can use `--with-included-apr` while configuring apache without any glitch. Just make sure that directories are named exactly as apr and apr-util and do not contain any version number etc. and yo don't need to run configure in apr and apr-util directory. Just place apr and apr-util as mentioned and start building your apache.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cd httpd-2.4.x/srcib/`
2. `chmod +x */build/*`
3. `./configure --with-included-apr....`

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename both utilities as apr and apr-utils without any version tail,
2. While installing from source mention exact path of apr directory like below.

./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/scrib/apr 
make 
make install